# MIPS reads 2 integer numbers and then print out the larger one

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm having trouble trying to complete a MIPS program that take to input integers and prints the larger of the two out.
My code:

```
#read 2 integer numbers and print out the larger one
.data # data section
    mes1: .asciiz "\n\nEnter the first integer number: "
    mes2: .asciiz "Enter the second integer number: "
    mes3: .asciiz "The larger integer number is: "
.text # code section
    li $v0, 4 #print a string "mes1"
    la $a0, mes1
    syscall

    li $v0, 5 #read the first integer
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0

    li $v0, 4 #print a string "mes2"
    la $a0, mes2
    syscall

    li $v0, 5 #read the second integer
    syscall
    move $t1, $v0

    addi $t0, $zero, -100  #Get larger integer (the first or the second)
    addi $t1, $zero, -100

    slt $s0, $t0, $t1
    bne $s0, $zero, mes3 
    syscall

    li $v0, 4 #print a string "mes3"
    la $a0, mes3 
    syscall

    li $v1, 1 #print the larger int number
    move $a0, $v0
    syscall


    li $v0, 10 # system call for exit
    syscall
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what issues you're having, what it's doing as opposed to what it should do etc

Comment: But clearly you're doing some strange arithmetics (why add -100?), you're jumping to a string label `mes3` instead of actual code label etc.

Comment: Mips uses `addi` with `$zero` to load immediates.  `-100` isn't actually getting added to the numbers read.  But it's not clear to me what the point of setting `$t0` and `$t1` to -100 is.  This needs an [mcve].  Also, include what you've figured out so far from using a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems with your approach.  First, I don't know why you're replacing both numbers with -100.  Second, you have a syscall after the conditional, which doesn't appear to serve any function to your problem. This code should work.

```
#read 2 integer numbers and print out the larger one

.data # data section
mes1: .asciiz "\n\nEnter the first integer number: "
mes2: .asciiz "Enter the second integer number: "
mes3: .asciiz "The larger integer number is: "

.text # code section
li $v0, 4 #print a string "mes1"
la $a0, mes1
syscall

li $v0, 5 #read the first integer
syscall
move $t0, $v0

li $v0, 4 #print a string "mes2"
la $a0, mes2
syscall

li $v0, 5 #read the second integer
syscall
move $t1, $v0

slt $s0, $t0, $t1
bne $s0, $zero, print_num  #jumps to print_num if $t0 is larger
move $t0, $t1  #else: $t1 is larger

print_num:
li $v0, 4 #print a string "mes3"
la $a0, mes3 
syscall

li $v0, 1 #print the larger int number
move $a0, $t0
syscall

li $v0, 10 # system call for exit
syscall
```

Comment: Doesn't `addi $t0, $zero, -100` in the OP's code actually overwrite the value in `$t0` with `-100`?  He's not adding anything, just replacing both inputs with a constant.

Comment: Yea, you're right.  Thanks for the catch.  Although replacing it with a constant still seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: Right, obviously a huge bug (rather than just a pointless offset to both that cancels out when you compare, unless one number wraps and the other doesn't).  I don't have any idea what the OP's intent was for those instructions either.

Answer (score 1):

```
.data # data section
    mes1: .asciiz "\n\nEnter the first integer number: "
    mes2: .asciiz "Enter the second integer number: "
    mes3: .asciiz "The larger integer number is: "

.text # code section
    li $v0, 4 #print a string "mes1"
    la $a0, mes1
    syscall

    li $v0, 5 #read the first integer
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0

    li $v0, 4 #print a string "mes2"
    la $a0, mes2
    syscall

    li $v0, 5 #read the second integer
    syscall
    move $t1, $v0

    slt $s0, $t0, $t1
    bne $s0, $zero, print_num  #jumps to print_num if $t0 is larger
    move $t1, $t0  #else: $t1 is larger

print_num:
    li $v0, 4 #print a string "mes3"
    la $a0, mes3 
    syscall`enter code here`

    li $v0, 1 #print the larger int number
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall
```

Comment: It's considered good etiquette to include a brief explanation of you answer.

Comment: The only difference is that the larger value is stored in $t1 so it should be used  rather than $t0